# Bashifying a test script

Tags: bash

Probably a very basic question for bash experts but I have a `test.sh` script.. Which has things like

```
python -m pytest tests/foo.py
python -m pytest tests/bar.py
python -m pytest tests/foobar.py
```

I am trying to like just put all these in a for loop containing only `[foo.py, bar.py.. ]`

What would be the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a simple `for` loop

```
for test in foo.py bar.py foobar.py
do
    python -m pytest "tests/$test"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Barmar's answer, incase you want to traverse through all files in `tests` directory:

```
for test in tests/*
do
    python -m pytest "tests/$test"
done
```